# Retrieving Amazon productinformation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I've found plenty of examples of retrieving product information in ASP, PHP and so on but not any in pure JavaScript without any server side code.

Is is possible with just JavaScript? Are there any wrapper classes available, or even just some example code?

Comment: Because of the same-origin policy, this is not possible unless Amazon provides jsonp as a workaround

Answer (score 1):

As stated in other answers, it is required to make a CORS request to Amazon PA-API.

I am working on a Chrome plugin where I want to fetch amazon products and display them. So, I need to use JavaScript for that but I always get cross-origin error.

The possible solution of that is using [CORS Anywhere API](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/) developed by [Rob--W](https://github.com/Rob--W)

```
var cors_api_url = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';
function doCORSRequest(options, printResult) {
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open(options.method, cors_api_url + options.url);
    x.onload = x.onerror = function() {
        printResult(
            options.method + ' ' + options.url + '\n' +
            x.status + ' ' + x.statusText + '\n\n' +
            (x.responseText || '')
        );
    };
    x.send(options.data);
}
(function() {
    var outputField = document.getElementById('output');
    new1();
    function new1() {
        // e.preventDefault();
        doCORSRequest({
            method: 'GET',
            url: url,
        }, function printResult(result) {
            //result contains the response
            //write your code here
        });
    };
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that amazon provides a jsonp version of their web services, so it is not possible directly. If you really want to do this you will have to use one of your servers as a proxy.

[Here](https://github.com/christianhellsten/amazon-json-api) is a library that wraps the amazon product web services in a json or jsonp layer, complete with example code (if you're hosting it yourself you can just do a regular ajax call and don't need jsonp, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Gabe is right.  You'll need to pass your requests through a proxy.

See: [This web API does not have CORS enabled; how can I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25315383/this-web-api-does-not-have-cors-enabled-how-can-i-use-it/29377193#29377193) for an example of how this works.

Answer (score 0):

Check this http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/index.htm

For a more generic use case you can use thrid party apis
 there are companies like INDIX that provide structured product information through api . Please click here for more details

https://developer.indix.com/docs#/reference/product-search

https://github.com/indix/indix-api-nodejs